# Date Convesion convert the date to previous date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to convert in a custom date format in IE9 of Windows 7 version but the `date.getUTCDate()` reuturns previous day's date. I have attached the Sample JS Fiddle.

```
//'Tue Apr 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013'
var date = new Date('Tue Apr 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013');
document.write( 
    (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" +
    date.getUTCDate() + "/" +
    date.getUTCFullYear()   
);
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QzKwE/67

Comment: You know what `UTC` is, right?

Answer (score 2):

A time of midnight in a timezone which is `UTC+530` converted to UTC time will indeed be on the previous day.

This is exactly what it is supposed to do. In fact, changing your fiddle to output the entire date and time in UTC reveals the detail:

http://jsfiddle.net/QzKwE/68/

```
input:
Tue Apr 25 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2013

output:
Wed, 24 Apr 2013 18:30:00 GMT
```

5h30m before midnight on the input date.